# Is there a way to use bincount with bin width = 0.1 in python?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, width, bin

I have something like
`[12.414261306701654, 10.52589457006108, 12.398125569114093, 11.900971715356471, 11.566273761189997, 10.31504117886884, 10.235859974871904, 10.25704925592012, 10.296557787801154, 10.19010244226054]`

say I want the count of occurrence in`(10,10.1)(10.1,10.2),...`

I think that `numpy.bincount`only takes integer bin width, however if I multiply my array by 10 and use `bincount`, when I plot the result later the `xscale` is also off by 10, and I don't know how can I get the accurate plot.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`np.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = [12.414261306701654, 10.52589457006108, 12.398125569114093, 11.900971715356471, 11.566273761189997, 10.31504117886884, 10.235859974871904, 10.25704925592012, 10.296557787801154, 10.19010244226054]
>>> counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, bins=np.arange(10, 12.6, 0.1))
>>> counts
array([0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 1])
```

Comment: So you're defining `counts` and `bin_edges` at the same time?

Comment: @LilMuji -- yes because that's what `histogram` returns.  In this case, I input the bin edges (`bins=np.arange(...)`), but `bins` can accept other types of arguments as well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this did work. But as long as I perform further calculations on the list the scale got messed up again

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to change the `scale` to 1/10 of its actual value?

Comment: @LilMuji -- I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you have a numpy array, you should be able to just divide it by 10 ...

Comment: when I do `plot[list]` the x-axis would be the `index number [i]`, y-axis would be the value.. I'm trying to get the x-axis to be `(1/10)i`